# Google Visualisation - Error type mismatch

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I keep getting the following error for my line chart - this was working fine a few days ago but now i get the following error...

Error: Type mismatch. Value 0 does not match type number in column index 1
 My code for the chart is as follows...

This would suggest that my value for displacement which is added to column one is not being recognised as a number, but I don't understand why?

```
drawDisplacementChart(xml, markers){
          //array to hold data
          var graph = [];

          //data table object
          var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

          //chart options
          var options = {title:'Displacement (m)/Time (minutes)', 
                  legend:{position:'bottom'},
                  is3d:true     
              };

              //get first point of route- displacement is distance travelled away from this point
              var startPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].getAttribute("lat"),markers[0].getAttribute("lng"));

              //loop through xml
              for(var i = 0; i<markers.length; i++){
                  //var to represent time - reading being taken every minute
                  var time = i+':00';
                  //find the current position in route
                  var current = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"),markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
                  //calculate displacement
                  var displacement = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(startPoint,current);
                  console.log(displacement);
                  //store values in array
                  graph[i] = [time, displacement];
              }

              //instantiates chart object
              var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));
              //set columns in data table
              dataTable.addColumn('string', 'time');
              dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Displacement');


              var array = [];
              //loop through stored values
              for(var i = 0; i<graph.length; i++){
                  //timeout to allow periodic addition
                       setTimeout(function(y){
                        array.push(graph[y]);
                        dataTable.addRows(array); 
                        //add value to chart
                        chart.draw(dataTable, options); 
                        //empty array for next iteration
                        array = [];
                  }, i*TIME, i);
              }

      }
```

Comment: can you show us `markers`?